# How to Treat Tensors and Matrices

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors

I am trying to figure out what to make of this boundary condition:
$$ n \cdot(-c\nabla\vec{u}-\alpha\vec{u}+\gamma)=0 $$
where $\gamma$ is of dimension $M \times M$, $\alpha$ is of dimension $M \times M \times m$, and $c$ is of dimension $M \times M \times m \times m$. In the case I'm currently interested in there are $M=2$ scalar equations and $m=2$ spatial dimensions in the problem. I want to write this condition out component-wise to get a better understanding of what it means however I am not quite sure how to handle this tensor-matrix multiplication.

The condition is being placed at the horizontal lines $y=0,1$ which make up the bottom and top of the domain so the normal vector is $n=(0,\mp1)$. Further, $\gamma$ is just a matrix and everything in the $()$ is being added so I know the result of that must just be a matrix but I have no idea how to figure out what the components would be. Any suggestions and/or references.

EDIT: Note that $\vec{u}$ is of dimension $M$ and $\vec{x}$ is of dimension $m$.

Comment: Is $\vec{u}$ of dimension $m$? Then $\alpha\,\vec{u}$ is clearly $\alpha_{ijk}\,u_k$ which has two free indices $i,j$ running over $1,...,M$. Does this help?

Comment: 1. $\vec{u}$ being of dimension $M$ makes $\alpha\,\vec{u}$ strictly speaking a bit ambiguous. It could be $\alpha_{ijk}\,u_i$ or $\alpha_{ijk}\,u_j$. 2. $\nabla\vec{u}$ is the Jacobi matrix. Assuming $\vec{u}$ depends on $m$ variables this Jacobi matrix has $M$ rows and $m$ columns.

Comment: @KurtG. Would it make sense to treat this as $c\nabla\vec{u}=c_{ijkl}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_k}=C_{il}$. So component $C_{11}=c_{1111}u_x + c_{1211}v_x + c_{1121}u_y+c_{1221}v_y$.

Comment: where above I'm taking $\vec{u}=(u,v)^T$ and $\vec{x}=(x,y)^T$ for the case of $M=m=2$

Comment: I would make sense. Strictly speaking that's also ambiguous because it could be $c_{ijkl}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_l}$. Whatever fits the ranges of the summed over indices $1,...,m$ resp. $1,...,M$. It is hard to give an answer to your question without the full background. Having said that: you probably know more about that background than anyone else.

Comment: I appreciate the help - do you have any suggestions for references on tensors in general? I find myself always quite confused when I have to practically work with them

Comment: Tensors in index notation is only one side of the full story - and that's the simplest. Just drop the $\sum$ sign and sum over doubly occurring dummy indices (Einstein convention). If you want to learn about tensor fields I recommend Sean Carroll's arXiv script or his book about General Relativity.

Comment: Here, $\vec{u}$ is of dimension $M$ while $\vec{x}$ is of dimension $m$